# Facebook API - How to display Wall on Tab?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know how this page is displaying the Wall? See bottom of tab. http://www.facebook.com/pages/Friedlich-Chiller/216826602036?v=app_178091127385#next
Looks like a plugin, but I can't find in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Cool, that's my page. ;)
I use the BandPage-App by rootmusic.com. Quite easy to use.

Hope, I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer at BandPage. We recently deprecated the Facebook wall as facebook has changed a number of things about their api and supporting a feature they no longer support was not possible. But to answer your question, we wrote code to fetch the facebook feed data and generated a "copy" of the facebook wall in our app.